# Recursive method works while debugging, but get's stuck when running from a JAR

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, recursion

I have the following methods for recursively retrieving images from a folder:

```
private Collection<Image> GetImages(File file) {
    Collection<Image> result = new LinkedList<Image>();

    if (file.isFile()) {
        result.add(new Image(file));
        return result;
    }

    for (File f : file.listFiles(new DirAndImagesFilter())) {

        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            {
                result.addAll(GetImages(f));
            }
        } else {
            result.add(new Image(f));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and here is DirAndImageFilter code:

```
public class DirAndImagesFilter implements FileFilter {

private final static String jpeg = "jpeg";
private final static String jpg = "jpg";
private final static String gif = "gif";
private final static String tiff = "tiff";
private final static String tif = "tif";
private final static String png = "png";

public boolean accept(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        return true;
    }

    String extension = getExtension(file);
    if (extension != null) {
        if (extension.equals(tiff)
                || extension.equals(tif)
                || extension.equals(gif)
                || extension.equals(jpeg)
                || extension.equals(jpg)
                || extension.equals(png)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/*
 * Get the extension of a file.
 */
static String getExtension(File f) {
    String ext = null;
    String s = f.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
        ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ext;
}
```

}

When I am running my application from Netbeans it works fine, but when I run JAR file (which is also generated by Netbeans). My application gets stuck in this method.

To my understanding JAR file should behave absolutely the same way as the application running in Netbeans. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're right that being in a jar should have no impact on the logic. I suspect the difference you're seeing is due to a different working directory being set when you run via the IDE vs running the jar. Can you post the implementation of DirAndImagesFilter? Additionally, you should be using file.list(new DirAndImagesFilter()) since listFiles will only return the files and not the directories.

Comment: did you print

    System.getProperty("user.dir");

Both times and see what directory youre working on?

Comment: @Chris you are right about file.list. However the strange thing that listFiles was listing both files and folders for me!

Comment: @Vitalij Despite the method's name, it's normal for `File.listFiles()` to also list directories.  What do you mean by "my application gets stuck"?

Comment: It is hard to debug JAR, what I am doing is writing to the external files some values and it seems that in never returns from GetImages method, even though it passes all unit tests while running from NetBeans

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've run into these kinds of things before.  I do not see anything wrong with your code you posted here.

My guess is that you are reading files that comes from the jar itself.  If that is the case, that is your problem.  Reading "files" from a jar does not work.

It often occurs when you try things like:

```java
SomeClass.class.getResource("myfile")
```

This can be be solved by working with input streams, i.e.

```java
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myfile")
```

This is a wild guess... hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, I am reading from a different location (From my desktop)